Generating multiple non intersecting polygons
I want to generate multiple Polygons for showing off properties polygons have visually/interactively. The only constraint i want is that no lines of the polygons intersect. polygons containing one another is actually something i explicitly want to be possible.
A soft constraint is i want the result to look interesting, which of course is not measurable. But what i basically mean by that is i want there to be polygons inside of each other and/or polygons which are concave and/or of different sizes. Basically the polygons should be distributed somewhat randomly and should have non-regular shapes and arrangements.
I've tried generating polygons and checking if their not intersecting them selves and iteratively add them if they're not intersecting any of the previous polygons, but the result is somewhat underwhelming. when the polygons have a lot of edges they are a lot more likely to intersect themselves and be discarded.
Is there a way to generate multiple polygons like previously mentioned more effectively?
I thought of maybe partitioning the space i want to generate the polygons in, but for now i didn't find a solution i'm quite happy with.
